# how to lookup a unique first instance

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a data table with customer numbers in Column A, dates in Column B and activities in Column C.  Each of the customer numbers is in the list multiple times -- each with different dates and activities.  On another sheet in the workbook, I would like to enter a lookup formula (I think) to return a list of ONLY the first (Earliest) instance of the customer (I would also like to show the activity on that date as well)

For example,

On sheet 1 (the big list), I have:

- ABC123   05/23/12  Ran
- ABC123   01/05/11  Walked
- ABC123   06/22/12 Sat
- ABC123   10/16/13  Walked
- ABC123   05/20/14  Ran
- DWR123  04/08/13  Ran
- DWR123  07/01/12  Sat
- DWR123  11/18/11  Ran

On sheet 2 (the "extract"), I would like to see the EARLIEST instance of that customer number -- and the date of that instance -- and (if possible), the activity performed on that date:

- ABC123   01/05/11  Walked
- DWR123  11/18/11  Ran

I would PREFER to not have to worry about the sort order on sheet 1, if possible.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting it really gets quite difficult, but easy with (on date, Oldest to Newest). If ABC123 is in A1 of your second sheet and the first sheet is called Sheet1, in second sheet:

in Row1 of say ColumnB: `=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$C,2,FALSE)`
in Row1 of say ColumnC: `=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet1!$A:$C,3,FALSE)`

(ie can copy across provided `2` is then changed to `3`) and both formulae copied down to suit.